# Why is my boards.txt file not being found?

Tags: arduino-uno, ino

I'm using the `ino` command line tool for the first time. When attempting to build my first sketch I run:
`ino build` in the project directory.

I get the following error:

```
Searching for Board description file (boards.txt) ... FAILED
Board description file (boards.txt) not found. Searched in following places: 
  - /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/arduino
  - /usr/local/share/arduino/hardware/arduino
  - /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino
```

What's going wrong here?

I've found an open issue here: https://github.com/amperka/ino/issues/240
But I'm wondering if anyone has a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

I got a hack to work  (macOS) by symlinking the files to where `ino` expected them to be.  But now I'm running into this issue: https://github.com/amperka/ino/issues/149

FWIW:

```
cd /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources;
ln -s Java ../Java;
cd /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/arduino;
ln -s boards.txt avr/boards.txt;
```

Did it for me as far as finding boards.txt goes.

Still Broken otherwise. (Not marking as answer)